# Prevent outlook mobile from automatically creating links which arent real

Tags: outlook, html-email

So I am creating a new email template but somehow outlook mobile thought it was a good idea to turn all the text which looks like an href (but really isnt) into a link. This takes place in any HTML tag, "h1", "p", "span", "div" etc.

Is there any way to prevent this stupid feature from rendering on other peoples their phones?

Here is the code (all styles are inlined so there is no stylesheet):

```
<h1 style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; Margin-bottom: 8px; Margin-left: 0; Margin-right: 0; Margin-top: 16px; color: #ffffff; padding: 0; font-size: 26px; line-height: 34px;">Order ID 204793</h1>
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; Margin-bottom: 24px; Margin-top: 0; line-height: 27px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; margin-bottom: 16px;">08/09/2018, 15:47</p>
```

Comment: Is there any way you could post your code so we can see what is going on?

Comment: Outlook will no do that. Check to see if you have a missing closing tag for your a tag

Comment: Yep, let's see the code. There are some global css style overrides that can help with this behaviour

Comment: @Gwesolo I have added the code (also note that we are talking about outlook MOBILE, the android application).

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? You make a reference to `class="lead mb"`, but you don't post the style sheet or other details. Three different people are trying to help you, why are you rejecting the help?

Comment: @Gwally As said all the styles are INLINED so the class has no effect on the result. All the class attributes are in the 'style: ...' attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable an email link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013625/how-to-disable-an-email-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap any text you don't want linked in a `<a>` tag of your own and style it so that it doesn't appear to be a link (e.g "color:#000000;text-decoration:none;"). You don't need to include an href attribute.

Comment: On Outlook for iOS you also have to set a `name` like `<a name="anyfakename" style="...">`, note that it seems like you cannot use a name that is an existing class, and each link must have a unique `name`, otherwise the styles will be ignored for strings that look like phone numbers.