# Disable automatic creation of hyperlinks in Android Outlook app

Tags: android, colors, outlook, hyperlink

How can I disable the automatic creation of hyperlinks in HTML email in the Outlook mail app on Android? I tried

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

in the head part of the HTML code. This takes care of automatic creation of phone number links, but automatic creation of hyperlinks is still active. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable an email link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013625/how-to-disable-an-email-link)