# How to prevent smart highlighting on mobile email clients? (Outlook)

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, mjml

I have sent a test email to **Outlook** and opened in **Outlook app of iOS** and the default style of the text for dates/times has its own color.

[image: example]

(The white/gray part is there just to hide the text, you can see the green-ish underline text (which is a date a time)

Apps don't allow debugging so it's difficult to say which class it might have been applied to the displayed HTML.

**How to prevent this behavior and have the text by the color defined in CSS?**

> Note: this is HTML generated via MJML. The transpiled HTML for that paragraph looks like the following:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px; word-break:break-word">
        <div style="font-family:helvetica; font-size:10px;">
            TEXT WITH DATE
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> `text-decoration: none` works to remove the underline style, but the color doesn't change (`color: white`) - with or without `!important`

Comment: `text-decoration-none` or `text-decoration: none;`?

Comment: @fxtrot good point. I fix the typo in the question (I checked in the code and it was `:none` already)

Comment: but there was another typo that caused a parsing issue. `text-decoration: none` works but the color doesn't change (`color: white`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable an email link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013625/how-to-disable-an-email-link)

Answer (score 2):

Solution to **avoid date/time auto-linking on iPhone**:

Adding:

- `&#8203;` (Zero Width Space character) between the date/time text parts
- `nbsp;` (Non-breaking space) for blank spaces in between

Example:

- Date (WITH smart linking/highlighting): November, 1st 10:15
- Non-linked date (WITHOUT smart linking/highlighting): `&#8203;`November`&#8203;`,`&nbsp;&#8203;`1st`&nbsp;`10`&#8203;`:`&#8203;`15

Answer (score 0):

Some devices auto link date and addresses bc it allows users to one-click add to their calendar or map apps.

To resolve you could wrap that copy with  with inline styling so when those devices link that copy it has preset styling for it. Smart phones will auto add the href portion.

Example:

```
<a style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">
 November 13, 2021
</a>
```